# Duplicate comment when flagged as off-topic

Tags: bug, status-completed, vote-to-close, automatic-comments

I experienced a strange thing, when viewing a question I decided to flag it as a duplicate, I open the flag modal and select "duplicate" and even find the duplicate question before I change my mind and decide to flag it as off-topic.

After having submitted the off-topic flag I noticed that the automatic "Possible duplicate of..." comment had still been posted, despite that I flagged it as off-topic.

[image: possible_dup]

And in my flag history:

[image]

Is this intentional?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The UI wasn't accounting for people changing their minds.

I've added a bit of logic to clear out the selected dupe target when clicking the "Closing" link, which should take care of this particular issue.

With you in the next build.

Answer (score 18):

This is definitely a bug, albeit a fairly minor one. I can repro it, so it afflicts both users with full close-vote privileges as well as those using the close vote dialog to flag.

Steps:

1. Find a question to close (not difficult).
2. Find a duplicate target, click the button to close the question as a duplicate, and type the URL to the duplicate in the textbox.
3. Change your mind, click the "Closing" link at the top of the close pop-up to go back to the main screen.
4. Pick another close reason (I believe any will do, but I picked one of the sub-items of off-topic).
5. Submit your close vote.

Your close vote gets cast for the reason you actually chose (the last one selected—in my case, off-topic), but the "possible duplicate" comment is still posted.

Presumably this is because the URL is still stored somewhere in the dialog, and the comment auto-generator is naïve enough to post the comment if the duplicate target URL is a non-null string.

Comment: _"(not difficult)"_ - heh.

Comment: If you need help for [step 1](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/php?sort=newest&pageSize=50)